# Do all modules inherit the Coin contract automatically or is there a required import?

Tags: pact-lang

When accepting payment for an NFT I am making, how do I ensure I can call coin.transfer and coin.details from my module?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So the only per-requisites are

1. Reference to the coin contract
2. The transfer capability

You can reference (call) functions on the coin contract by simple calling them like normal functions by doing `coin.transfer` etc.
You can also "import" the whole coin module by doing `(use coin)` in your contract. This imports all the functions in the coin contract so you can call them like `transfer` instead of `coin.transfer` .
But this can cause unexpected bugs if not used with caution, so I recommend always calling them like `coin.transfer` etc

You need to make sure the "TRANSFER" capability is granted. This can be passed in / specified by the caller when calling the contract.
If your contract is the "owner" of the account (i.e. there's a balance for the contract) you can use the `install-capability` which will let contract grant itself the capability to do transfers for its account